# Looping through multiple loops in

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
DROP PROCEDURE fillBin;
DELIMITER $$
 CREATE  PROCEDURE fillBin(IN a INT(11), IN b INT(11), IN c INT(11), IN d INT(11), IN e     INT(11))
wholeblock:BEGIN
 DECLARE i INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1;
 DECLARE j INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1;
 DECLARE k INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1;
 DECLARE l INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1;
 DECLARE m INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1;
 DECLARE strA VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
 DECLARE strB VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
 DECLARE strC VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
 DECLARE strD VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
 DECLARE strE VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
 DECLARE strF VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';

 SET strA = 'A';
 SET strB = 'G';
 SET strC = 'R';
 SET strD = 'S';
 SET strE = 'B';
 SET strF= '';

 WHILE i < (a+1) DO
 SET strA=CONCAT(strA,i) ;
WHILE j < (b+1) DO
SET strB = CONCAT(strB,j);
    WHILE k < (c+1) DO
    SET strC =CONCAT(strC,k);
        WHILE l < (d+1) DO
        SET strD = CONCAT(strD,l);
            WHILE m < (e+1) DO
            SET strE = CONCAT(strE,m);
            SET strF = CONCAT(strA, strB, strC, strD, strE);
            INSERT INTO BIN (`aisle`, `room`, `rack`, `shelf`, `bin`, `barcode`, `warehouse_id`) 
            VALUES(strA,strB, strC, strD, strE, strF, 1);

SET m=m+1;
SET strE = 'B';
END WHILE;
SET l=l+1;
SET strD = 'S';
END WHILE;
SET k=k+1;
SET strC = 'R';
END WHILE;
SET j=j+1;
SET strB = 'G';
END WHILE;
SET i=i+1;
SET strA = 'A';
END WHILE;
END $$

//calling the procedure
CALL fillBin(1, 1, 1, 2, 2);
```

My procedure inserts the values: A1G1R1S1B1 and A1G1R1S1B2. And the inner loop breaks.

but the correct insertion should be: A1G1R1S1B1 and A1G1R1S1B2 and A1G1R1S2B1 and A1G1R1S2B2.

The insert is obviously incomplete. How should I place my insert statement or change the looping as to cater the needs?

Please help. Thanks

Comment: This is so un-SQL like that it suggests you are going about your wider business problem completely the wrong way, which makes this sound like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  How exactly is this procedure used?

Comment: The other ways would be, a. writing a code around it and saving the entries into the db. b. creating insert queries through an Excel, may be, and then running all of 'em. I thought my approach could be easier.

Comment: *How exactly* is this procedure *used*?  What is the *wider business problem* that you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have to clean my db and re-populate all the entries. I know the dimensions which will be input parameter to my procedure. And calling this procedure would fill the database. I know this may appear to be a bs solution, if so, please help me with the approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't use simple SQL to do this task ?
Look at the following example
We need a table with a seqence of numbers from 1 to X - where X is a maximum number whenever we need.

```
CREATE TABLE numbers(
  x int primary key auto_increment
);

INSERT INTO numbers
SELECT null FROM information_schema.columns;

SELECT max( x ) FROM numbers;
| MAX( X ) |
|----------|
|      558 |
```

And now the below simple select will generate all required records for us
(see this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e5c4b/7
 - you will need to scroll to the bottom of the page to see a result of the query):

```
SET @strA = 'A';
SET @strB = 'G';
SET @strC = 'R';
SET @strD = 'S';
SET @strE = 'B';
SET @strF= '';

SET @a = 2;
SET @b = 2;
SET @c = 2;
SET @d = 2;
SET @e = 2;


SELECT *,
       CONCAT(strA, strB, strC, strD, strE) strF,
       1 As warehouse_id
FROM (
  SELECT Concat(@strA,x) strA
  FROM numbers 
  WHERE x <= @a
) A
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT Concat(@strB,x) strB
  FROM numbers
  WHERE x <= @b
) B
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT Concat(@strC,x) strC
  FROM numbers
  WHERE x <= @c
) C
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT Concat(@strD,x) strD
  FROM numbers
  WHERE x <= @d
) D
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT Concat(@strE,x) strE
  FROM numbers
  WHERE x <= @e
) E
```

And now just place an INSERT statement at the top of the above query:

```
INSERT INTO BIN (`aisle`, `room`, `rack`, `shelf`, `bin`, `barcode`, `warehouse_id`) 
    SELECT *,
           CONCAT(strA, strB, strC, strD, strE) strF,
           1 As warehouse_id
    FROM (
      SELECT Concat(@strA,x) strA
      FROM numbers 
      WHERE x <= @a
    ) A
    CROSS JOIN
    (
      SELECT Co .....
    ........
    ........
    ........
```